# Help me find model of recumbent bike?

Tags: identify-this-bike, recumbent

I am new to the community but used to ride pretty heavily for 2-3 years back in college (2015-2018) and am hoping to get back into the hobby, and am hoping to track down my old bike make/model.

I owned a lovely recumbent, it had all the necessary items. It was SWB and USS. The front tire was 16"x 1-3/8" and the rear wheel was 700c (x 20-25c). It also had a built in fairing mount up front.

Despite the 3 years of riding, and approx 1300 miles I put on this girl, I have [exactly 3 photos with her even in them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SC0RK.jpg).

These are trash photos, I understand. The ones I took of her when I got her, and when I was riding more actively, were all on a phone that I ended up losing to the bottom of a lake. I'm hoping that these 3 and the specs I have are helpful enough. I am approx 5'10" in the picture, if that helps any.

I have been looking all over, and unfortunately specs of bents just aren't super easy to come by.

Additional details: I did at one time track then the make/model of the bike, so I know it wasn't a home brew, although there may have been modifications to her before I got her, specifically in the seat area. It had 3 gears up front and 7-8 in the back. Shimano shifters. The seat mounted on with 4 bolts, but that might have been modded. The chain crossed over itself, and it did have an idler, that [basically looked like this](https://www.pistonbikes.com/product-p/jb67613.htm), although it was yellow. I believe the frame was straight from the rear gear to the front one, but at an angle (you can kind of see the angle in the picture) so the bar didn't have a bend in it, [like the Vision bikes do](http://visionrecumbentinfo.com/images/r40/sa2.jpg). The front wheel was also VERY close to the seat,and the handle was actually above the frame as it was heading towards the pedals, although still under the seat, which you can see in the picture. It had a rack on the back, aluminum and thin, but that could have been modded as well. I bought it in March 2015, on craigslist, in Phoenix. I believe I remember the manufacturer was from the west side of the country, but that might be incorrect.

That's about all I can remember. If you have any specific questions, I might be able to job my memory. I don't have any specific serial numbers or anything like that unfortunately.

Thank you all, hopefully we can find it.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: "I did at one time track then the make/model of the bike" ; do you recall the make/brand of the bike (or did your previous research not result in a make/brand of the bike)?

Comment: I believe the stem in the picture is a Tranz-x stem (similar to this model: https://www.ebay.com/itm/281843058254

Comment: Do you recall the frame material and/or brand name of the wheels perhaps?

Comment: Problem is, 'bents tend to be put together with parts from several sources, rather than the frame manufacturer sourcing most pieces.  So there are fewer distinguishing features, and two "identical" bikes just days apart from the manufacturer can have different parts.

Comment: What happened to your old bike that you can't use that?   Is it available at all?

Comment: @Maarten-Monicaforpresident I tracked the make/brand back when I got it. When I bought it, it had a make and model printed on it. Frame material was soild and heavy. I would think steel. Front wheel (and maybe rear) had a kevlar weave in it.

Comment: @Criggie I lost it in a move. I have no clue how I lost a whole bike. But I moved into a new place in June 2017, and it didn't make the move

Comment: Upshot - looks like you might be better going to a shop that specialises in recumbents, and trying out what they have.  Finding something that you like may be easier than finding what you had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

S&B is the manufacturer.
they were the first American Company to make Recumbents.
39 years in the business.
Closed the doors years ago.
I had the Trike model and the Boom configuration did not adjust, only the seat position.
Here is the video on Youtube.

Comment: So you're proposing that OP's bike is a S&B?  Why do you say that?  Please use [edit] to show the similarities.  Video link shows a lot of trikes, both tadpoles and deltas, and very few two-wheeled bents.

Comment: S&B Malibu, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Those photos miss out most of the useful parts for identification.

It could be almost any USS SWB bent, but a quick scan of 
 https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=USS+recumbent+SWB&oq=USS+recumbent+SWB

suggests it may be something like

1. Haluzak Horizon 
    [image] 
    from https://bicycleman.com/brands-we-dont-stock/haluzak-recumbents/  but I note the stem is different.
2. HP Velotechnic Street Machine 
    [image] 
    from https://www.hpvelotechnik.com/produkte/sm/gt/pressespiegel/recumbentcyclist_070804_e.html

Comment: There are plenty of different makers and designs, you may have to get a leg over several to see which ones feel "right"  and that will generally require a bike shop that retails in recumbents.   Good luck !

Comment: The HP Velotechnic doesn’t have the stubby front derailleur mount shown in OP’s second picture.

Comment: @michael yes, but other Street Machine models do, and it’s a much better match to other features, like the handlebar and stem positioning. I think he nailed it.